# Hook, line and sinker

Tags: phrases, idioms, word-usage, phrase-usage

I learned that "hook, line and sinker" is used to emphasize that someone has been completely deceived or tricked. I'd like to know whether it is appropriate to use the phrase in a formal situation. I also would like to know some examples of the usage of the phrase.

Comment: Commonly, *He fell for it, hook, line, and sinker*. A fishing reference - gullible as a fish. Colorful, not formal, but an orator could make use of the homespun quality.

Comment: Yeah, it's not "formal", but it is well-understood and not offensive.

Comment: With your rep you surely know how to do the research online?

Comment: @banuyayi Thanks. Yeah, but I just wanted to grasp its nuance which I couldn't cleary get from the research...

Comment: People ask questions like "is it ok to use in a formal situation" without considering that there is a wide variety of formal situations: a newspaper article, a scientific paper, a business invoice, various types of legal document, a brochure for customers of your business, a letter to a potential employer, your self-written wedding vowels, a literary novel...

Comment: Do you know what a sinker is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is idiomatic and can be used in both formal and casual conversations. Look at these example sentences in "Dictionary for Idioms by FARLEX".

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hook%2c+line%2c+and+sinker